# Remove or change "visible on new button" default "Item" Content type from list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, content-type

Hi I am creating my own content types and assigning them to my new lists like so

```
var contentType = clientContext.Web.ContentTypes.GetById(ContentTypeID);
list.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
list.ContentTypes.AddExistingContentType(contentType);
```

This works well, however, I do not need to have the default content type attached to these lists. See below.

[image: The Default Content Type]

How can I remove it via code?

Researching more into it, I now know there is a variable called `UniqueContentTypeOrder` and I try to apply the new content type ID I want on to it. For example.

```
IList<ContentTypeId> ctoFolder = new List<ContentTypeId>();

ctoFolder.Add(contentType.Id);

list.RootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = ctoFolder;
list.RootFolder.Update();
list.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

However, when executing the query I am getting an "Unknown error" in the catch

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ContentTypeCollection.GetById](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.contenttypecollection.getbyid.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method to get the specific content type and then delete it from the list.

```
$contentTypeID="<content type id>"
#Delete the content type from the list
list.ContentTypes.GetById($contentTypeID).DeleteObject()
```

Comment: Thanks, worked it out shortly after. Cheers for posting.